# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\alpha f(x) \mathrm{d} x \leqslant \frac{1}{1+\alpha^2}$ for any $\alpha \leq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

let $f$ be a non-negative function on $(-\infty, + \infty)$, satisfying
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2 f(x) \mathrm{d} x=1, \quad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x f(x) \mathrm{d} x=0,
$$
prove that for any $\alpha \leq 0$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\alpha f(x) \mathrm{d} x \leqslant \frac{1}{1+\alpha^2} .
$$

**My thought**:
$\int_R (x-a)^2 f(x) dx = 1+\alpha^2$, which gives $\int_R x^2 f(x+\alpha) dx=1+\alpha^2$. Let $g(x)=f(x+\alpha)$ and then similarily we have $\int_R x^2 g(x) dx = 1+\alpha^2$, $\int_R x g(x) dx = -\alpha$, $\int_R g(x) dx = 1$. Then we only need to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^0 g(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{1+\alpha^2}$.

Comment: It is easy to deduce that $f(x)$ is an even function so $$ \int_{R} f(x) dx = 2 \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) dx $$ so $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha} f(x) dx  = \frac{1}{2} - \int_{\alpha}^0 f(x) dx $$

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Why is $f$ even? (and how would it help?)

Comment: @AnneBauval I thought it because $\int_{R} x f(x) dx = 0 = \int_0^\infty (x f(x) - x f(-x)) dx$ so $\implies f(x) = f(-x)$ and it is given that $\int_{R} f(x) dx = 1 = 2\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$

Comment: $\dots\not\Rightarrow f(x) = f(-x),$ and even if $\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha} f(x) dx  = \frac{1}{2} - \int_{\alpha}^0 f(x) dx$ were true, I cannot see how it would have helped.